# Can I create a link from a website which opens Wechat app on a mobile?

Tags: wechat

I know that I can post a QR code and if someone scans it on their phone, it will open Wechat app.

But what if they are already on their phone, browsing the site? They obviously cannot scan the QR code if they are on the mobile.

I read in another question that Wechat removed the use of URL protocols.

This leaves me with a problem.

If a user is on their mobile phone browsing a website, and the website wants to link to their Wechat profile so that the user can click or do something to open their Wechat app to the profile, how do I do it?

On the desktop version of my site, I show a QR code. On the mobile version of the site, showing the QR code doesn't mean much if they are already on their phone and can't scan the code! How do I link the Wechat profile so it opens the app and they can connect with me?

Do I simply have to show my username and they have to go open the app and look me up manually? Is that the only option?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<a href="weixin://">WeChat</a>` - that will open the WeChat app on the user's phone.

At the moment, there's no way to open the app to a specific user or profile.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Is this still true today?